# How do i find the calling file location?

Tags: php, variables, filesystems

I am trying to locate the location of file being displayed in php.

I have a small file which can be included by any file wither from root or from inside any folder.

i need to print out the location of the.

for long explanation: my config file is config.php located in root location of website i.e localhost/site1/test/. It contains `print $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`. it is being included by index.php in root location and also by database.php inside the includes folder of root.

I get two different result:

1. localhost/site1/test/, when i include config.php in index.php
2. localhost/site1/test/includes, when i include config.php in
   database.php

I would like to get localhost/site1/test in both cases. So what can be the choice instead `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

Answer (score 0):

Try `dirname(__FILE__)` (or `__DIR__` if using PHP >= 5.3).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Its giving me absolute path. i want something like web browsable like localhost/... not c:/abc/xyx/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `print_r($_SERVER)` you will surely find what you are looking for in that array.

**Update:**

```
<?php
print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
?>
```

Comment: sorry i am not getting the one... plz help

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])`